# Prestashop 1.7 : dni is invalid when creating a supplier from B.O

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Every time i'm trying to create a **supplier** from **BackOffice**, an error message is appeared: **"dni is invalid"** because invalid characters.

i have changed **"isDniLite"** in **"validate.php"** file but no luck.

i need that field to accept anything.

I am using Prestashop **V1.7.7.0**

Need help please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to go to the file `yourshop\classes\Validate.php`

In this file scroll down until you see `function isDniLite($dni)` and add following line:

```
public static function isDniLite($dni)
{
    return $dni; // Crezzur: Don't check, just accept variable input.
    // Disable the old return just to be sure:
    // return empty($dni) || (bool) preg_match('/^[0-9A-Za-z-.]{1,16}$/U', $dni);
}
```

The best practice is to write an override for this. But this is your free choice.

**Update:**
Additional there is another place where a check for DNI is placed

You have to go to the file `yourshop\js\validate.js`

In this file scroll down until you see `validate_isDniLite(s)` and add following line:

```
function validate_isDniLite(s)
{
    return s;
    // var reg = /^[0-9a-z-.]{1,16}$/i;
    // return reg.test(s);
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply @Crezzur . it's not working sorry, i have also cleared cache and forced compilation but no luck. i also tested 'return true;' but nothing is working. I am not expert to make an override sorry. Any idea? i am really stucked. thanks :)

Comment: I have updated my question, can you try this?

Comment: Then my first option should work. Try to put your backoffice in debug modus and see what this does.

Comment: Found this file in debug mode. 'src/PrestaShopBundle/Form/Admin/Sell/Supplier/SupplierType.php' but i can't figure out what's wrong. any hint please? Thanks @Crezzur

Comment: Search `->add('dni', TextType::class`  and remove the content inside **constraints** like this `'constraints' => []`

Comment: Problem solved! finally thank you very much @Crezzur

Comment: I think the code snippet for `function isDniLite` in the answer is buggy. The return type in the commented-out code is boolean. So the new code should be `return TRUE;` not `return $dni;`.